# LinkedList vs ArrayList - asking point of view for implementation ideas

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, linked-list

i want to use a list which will store objects of some type (lets say for simplicity - books) so i can show them in a listview object. 
im kinda new to this, so i ask for the help of more advanced and experienced users about the following debates -

1. which one to use? linkedlist is something im familiar with. however, how do i make the app maintain the list? should i save the details of each object in a XML? if i do that, isnt it just better to use Arraylist? (please exclude in your answer things related to proccessing time).
2. if not via xml - how do i 'store' a list for later use even when the app is shut down and later on activated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must storage your data into SQLite. Android provides a very easy way. Look at this tutorial: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 1):

ArrayLists are good to use when you want *random access* via an *indexed lookup*. They're just as well suited for iterating through as `LinkedList`s.

OTOH, `LinkedList` doesn't need to be resized, it only runs out of room when you run out of memory to hold more nodes. If you have lots of data growth, or you're doing lots of sequential add/removes, then `LinkedList`s will win out in performance.

Sometimes you need both *random access* and *growth*, in those cases you need to make a judgment call on which criteria you want to be more performant.

In your current use case, I'd probably choose an ArrayList, you'll likely know how big the list should be, it won't be changing in size that often, and if you want to display this thing in a GUI, you're likely to need to do indexed lookups.

As far as storing the list, XML is as good a means as any, CSV files (or plain line-delimited text files), YAML, JSON and even class serialization are some alternatives, choose what's easiest and most convenient for you.

Comment: the resizing of the ArrayList is actually very fast, and does not really affect the global complexity of adding an element, which tends to o(1) on the long term. _removing_ an element, on the other hand, is o(n) no matter what, against o(1) for a linkedlist

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer ArrayList over LinkedList because it has methods to manipulate the size of the array that is used internally to store the list

If i am going to use it as a stack, queue, or double-ended queue then I would use a LinkedList